# AngularJS ng-view doesn't reload data

Tags: angularjs

I don't know why (sure?) ng-view doesn't reload datas changed from controller. The code is like this:

```
$scope.reloadUserInfo = function() {
    APIs.tot_of(null).then(function(result) {
        $scope.tot_of = result;
        APIs.info_of(null).then(function(result) {
            $scope.info_of = result;
        });
    });
};
```

$scope.info_of is reloaded in all view but not in ng-view like this.

```
    <div id="page-content">
        info_of or other params are reloaded
        <div ng-view>Here, using routes, info_of or other params aren't reloaded.</div>
    </div>
```

I created a function that reload info at every refresh or change route, so if I change route the ng-view data reload but if I use ng-click, data doesn't reload in ng-view. Who know why? Thanks.

Update with plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/R5fCJykwbm2q18Px4BrZ?p=preview

Comment: I don't think you are providing enough information for anybody to help you. Could you provide more code? Maybe a plnkr?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/R5fCJykwbm2q18Px4BrZ?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your `ng-view` directive creates a child scope. If you remove the controller in your route, or in your view display `{{$parent.name}}` then it will work.